# Trapping wireless clients and redirecting them to an authentication page

Tags: wifi

When a customer comes to surf the web on my guest wifi, he should be redirected to my company's page where he is asked a password. If that password is correct, then the user should be allowed to reach the destination

How do I implement this?

Answer (score 3):

You need a captive portal software. There are some freeware too. See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Captive_portal

Answer (score 3):

this is a common function of many wireless routers. it's called a captive portal.